# Program not recognizing repeated composite container in protobuf?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

I have a protobuf with a repeated field of People stored within an Address Book.

So far, I start things off like this:

```
 addressbook = Book()
 jake = addressbook.persons.add()
 jake.phone = 33333

 lucy = Person()
 lucy.phone = 44444

 taylor = Person()
 taylor.phone = 55555

 addressbook.persons.extend([lucy, taylor])
```

I have another file that's supposed to go through the addressbook and compare it to another addressbook to see if it's the same addressbook. So far, I do it like this:

```
#book_vars are variables within the address book, like people 
for item in book_vars:
    if isinstance(getattr(book1, item), collections.Iterable:
        do stuff
```

However, it never goes into the if loop. Anyone have any ideas why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class that protobufs uses to represent repeated fields is not the Python native list type and does not inherit `collections.Iterable`, therefore your code will not detect repeated fields as you intend. A better way to tell the type of each field in a protobuf message is to use its [descriptor](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python/google.protobuf.descriptor.Descriptor-class), available as `MyMessageType.DESCRIPTOR`.

Comment: Excellent answer, but just goes to show how difficult Google has made it to work with protobufs.  Why make _everything_ about them different from how the rest of the language works??  This is not just Python.  In general, create packages that seamlessly integrate within the language.  I suspect this is why [even Google says to use Avro instead of protobufs](https://g.co/bard/share/de7be00823fe).